# Why are custom objects not equivalent keys for a HashMap?

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, key, hashmap

I'm having trouble using my own class as a key for a HashMap

```
 public class ActorId {
     private final int playerId;
     private final int id;

     ActorId(int playerId, int id) {
         this.playerId = playerId;
         this.id = id;
     }

     public boolean equals(ActorId other) {
         return this.id == other.id && this.playerId == other.playerId;
     }

     public int hashCode() {
         int hash = 1;
         hash = hash * 31 + playerId;
         hash = hash * 31 + id;
         return hash;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return "#" + playerId + "." + id;
     }

     public int getPlayerId() {
         return playerId;
     }
 }
```

Here is a failing JUnit test

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;
 import java.util.Map;
 import org.junit.Test;

 public class ActorIdTest {
     @Test
     public final void testAsMapKey() {
         ActorId a = new ActorId(123, 345);
         ActorId b = new ActorId(123, 345);

         assertTrue(a.equals(b));
         assertEquals(a.hashCode(), b.hashCode());

         // Works with strings as keys
         Map<String, String> map1 = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

         map1.put(a.toString(), "test");
         assertEquals("test", map1.get(a.toString()));
         assertEquals("test", map1.get(b.toString()));
         assertEquals(1, map1.size()); 

         // But not with ActorIds
         Map<ActorId, String> map2 = new java.util.HashMap<ActorId, String>();

         map2.put(a, "test");
         assertEquals("test", map2.get(a));
         assertEquals("test", map2.get(b)); // FAILS here
         assertEquals(1, map2.size()); 

         map2.put(b, "test2");
         assertEquals(1, map2.size());
         assertEquals("test2", map2.get(a));
         assertEquals("test2", map2.get(b));
     }
 }
```

Comment: You say it fails on `...map2.get(b)` - you have no such key in your Map. You've only added one object to the map, the `a` instance.

Comment: @Björn Yes, the two ActorId objects are equal and have the same hashcode, so they should return the same value from the map.

Comment: Heh, sorry! Just stepped out of bed, should've read the whole code block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change

```
public boolean equals(ActorId other) {
    ....
}
```

to

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    ....
}
```

---

**Tip of the day:** Always use `@Override` annotation.

If you had used the `@Override` annotation, the compiler would have caught the error and said:

> The method equals(ActorId) of type ActorId must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: @MGwynne - your comment is misleading.  1) the HashMap API **specifies** that `equal(Object)` is used.  2) simply changing the signature of `get` wouldn't change the behaviour.  It would be impossible to implement a `V get(K)` method that actually used the `boolean T.equals(K)` method without passing in a `Class<K>` object and using reflection to find and call the `equals` method.

Comment: @Stephen C - can you point me towards where the HashMap API specifies that it uses equals(Object), other than in the type signature? As far as I am aware, the get method simply calls the equal method on the objects. I highly doubt it specifically casts them to object, as this is already given by the type signature. The only point is that the get method specifies *in the type signature* that it takes an object and so the overloaded equals method is hidden. If the signature were changed to `V get (K key)` then it would work as the @dlundquist expected. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Of course, you can't simply go and change this easily, nor was I suggesting it. Also there are good reasons, based in the Java's concept of Object equality, for the signature taking an Object, I was just trying to point out why the ActorId equals method wasn't called even though one might naively think it would be.

Comment: @MGwyne - yes you are missing something.  You say *"it is also because HashMap.get takes an Object, not an ActorId.  Otherwise it would work."*.  My point is that it wouldn't work even if HashMap.get did take an ActorId!  You'd also need to change the declaration of the type parameter K ... or use reflection.  By the way, it is the signature that specifies the behaviour ... because with K defined as it is, this is the only possible meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, but you also need to override the `equals` method inherited from `Object`.

Add this to your `ActorId` class:

```
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(other == null || other.getClass() != getClass())
        return false;
    return equals((ActorId)other);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely must override the method equals(Object), and for certain implementation of a Map (HashMap) it is also necesary that you overrdide the method hashCode().

I had the same problem, and without the custom hashCode implementation the equals method of the class "ActorId" was never called.

Answer (score 0):

By default  Java  invokes boolean `equals(Object obj);`
So, you login is correct but if you want  to OVERRIDE equals() use Object as a parameter and and check the class by `instanceOf` or `getClass()` and do a class casting.

```
if (obj instanceOf ActorId) {
    ActorId other = (ActorId)obj;
    ... compare fields
}
```