# Java performance optimization

Tags: java, performance

For a JOGL game I get very low fps, now with some testing I found out the problem is not in the JOGL part, but in pure Java calculations. I need to define a lot of float variables, which takes up 90% of the time.

I have tested for 45 float variables, where only 16 get an initial value. The rest is just `float z1; float z2;`, etc. This took around 5-10 milliseconds, according to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

But this code with the 45 floats is in a method called by a double loop. In total this method is called 49 times (7*7). All this is inside the JOGL method to draw the game in a JFrame, but because of this many float variables it takes a total of 100ms, which means only 10fps.

So basically the problem is that I have to initialize 45*49=2205 floats. Is there any way to optimize this to get a better fps?

For example, would a double be faster than a float? Or would it help to define the variables first outside the loop, and give them their value inside the loop? Does anyone know a way to make this code run faster? Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT

As requested, here is the source code:

```
for (int x = -4; x < 3; x++) { // Loops 7 times
    for (int y = -4; y < 3; y++) { // Loops 7 times
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float z0  = terrain.getHeight(x-1, y-1); // Simple method, but takes up about half of the time
        float z1  = terrain.getHeight(x  , y-1);
        float z3  = terrain.getHeight(x+1, y-1);
        float z4  = terrain.getHeight(x+2, y-1);
        float z5  = terrain.getHeight(x-1, y  );
        float z6  = terrain.getHeight(x  , y  );
        float z7;
        float z8;
        float z9;
        float z10 = terrain.getHeight(x+1, y  );
        float z11 = terrain.getHeight(x+2, y  );
        float z12;
        float z13;
        float z14;
        float z15;
        float z16;
        float z17;
        float z18;
        float z19;
        float z20;
        float z21;
        float z22;
        float z23;
        float z24;
        float z25;
        float z26;
        float z27;
        float z28;
        float z29;
        float z30;
        float z31;
        float z32;
        float z33 = terrain.getHeight(x-1, y+1);
        float z34 = terrain.getHeight(x  , y+1);
        float z35;
        float z36;
        float z37;
        float z38 = terrain.getHeight(x+1, y+1);
        float z39 = terrain.getHeight(x+2, y+1);
        float z40 = terrain.getHeight(x-1, y+2);
        float z41 = terrain.getHeight(x  , y+2);
        float z43 = terrain.getHeight(x+1, y+2);
        float z44 = terrain.getHeight(x+2, y+2);
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
        // Some other code where I use these variables.
        // Takes between 0-1 ms in total.
    }
}
```

EDIT

I now tested the getHeight() method, and it takes up about half of the time. The seven variables which use this method add up to about 5 ms, where the total is 10. The following is the code used in getHeight():

```
public float getHeight(float x, float y) {
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x, y);
    for (Entry<Coordinate, Float> e : heightMap.entrySet()) { // heightMap = HashMap<Coordinate, Float>
        if (e.getKey().x == c.x && e.getKey().y == c.y) {
            System.out.println("getHeight: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) + " ms");
            return e.getValue();
        }
    }
    return 0f;
}
```

Coordinate is a class I made myself, it has a constructor with two float parameters for x and y, and saves them public, globally in the class itself.

The reason why I am not using heightMap.get(c), is because this always throws a NullPointerException, while the code given above never reaches the last line of `return 0f;`.

EDIT

Found the solution to the problem in this [link] ([Why are custom objects not equivalent keys for a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241927/why-are-custom-objects-not-equivalent-keys-for-a-hashmap)) question, namely that I had to add `public boolean equals(Object other)` and `public int hashCode()` to my custom Coordinate class. Now the getHeight method can work with heightMap.get(c), which removes the loop in there and makes the program a lot faster. The total (with 49 loops) takes around 1 ms now.

Comment: It will definitively help to do the less operations possible inside the loops.

Comment: Without seeing some sample code, I'm not sure there's anything that can be said here.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: On my machine, it takes 649 milliseconds to generate 2205 random floats, initialize an array of 2205 floats with these random values and print them to System.out, 1000 times. So initializing 2205 floats with random values and printing them takes 0.65 milliseconds. I don't see how it could take 100 milliseconds just to initialize 2205 floats on your machine. You're probably not measuring correctly, and you're probably trying to optimize the wrong part. Without code, we can't say nothing more, anyway.

Comment: You have not said exactly what it is you're trying to achieve with your code. Why do you need the forty-nine float values? What does their data represent? There might be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Please post your code to get better idea.

Comment: Wow, did you ever heard about arrays?

Comment: Re-use the float variables by using some intelligence in looping.

Comment: It costs virtually nothing to "initialize" those uninitialized vars.  What does cost (a little) is simply having so many, as your stack frame gets to be too large to easily fit a single cache line.

Comment: The reason why I need the loops is because of the terrain I'm drawing for the game, for now the world is only 7 meters long (x) and 7 meters wide (y), so I need to calculate every single square. For the floats, they are for making the terrain smooth instead of big squares. For the fact that I said that I have 2205 floats, it's not really true because the 49 floats only exist inside the loop, so at any point in time I have at most 49 floats (from this code)

Comment: Can you inline your floats?

Comment: I guess I found out that the problem is not in the actual defining the floats, as many people suggested, but in the getHeight() method. I edited the question once again to give the source code of this method, and it uses another loop because the hashmap.get() is not working for a custom class I made. Maybe I should change that class to make the get() method work?

Comment: You have a `println` in `getHeight`. Take it out, and you'll zoom.

Comment: When I have a loop that takes a long time to run, I generally see two approaches for optimization: Make each iteration of the loop run faster and/or have fewer iterations.  Since it only runs 49 times, optimize the contents of the loop first.

Comment: I didn't even notice the `System.out.println`.  Good catch!  That will slow this down by a whole lot.

Comment: As mentioned in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241927/why-are-custom-objects-not-equivalent-keys-for-a-hashmap) the problem was that I had to add `public boolean equals(Object other)` and `public int hashCode()` to make the hashmap.get() method work, now the total program (with the 49 loops) takes around 1 ms, which is fair enough :D Thanks for helping everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Full Screen Exclusive Mode must be used for some operating systems to give you enough resources.

Defining variables outside of the loop will not help, as Java optimizes your code and defining variables inside a loop actually gives Java hints to increase performance. What I think (and I can only guess, since you posted no code) is, that you may consider using an array of longs. They are very effective to work with in a loop and they're also allocated one after another in your memory, so cache can be used effectively.

To me, fillings 2025 Longs takes slightly above **one millisecond**, including calls to random.nextLong() method.

```
public Long fillLongs(int numberofLongs) {

    long[] longs = new long[numberofLongs];
    Random r = new Random();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (long l : longs) {
        l = r.nextLong();
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return end - start;

}
```

Using **parallel stream**, this task takes even less time. Often under 1 ms.

```
public Long fillLongs(int numberofLongs) {

    Long[] longs = new Long[numberofLongs];
    List<Long> longList = Arrays.asList(longs);
    Random r = new Random();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    longList.parallelStream().forEach(l -> {
        l = r.nextLong();
    });

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return end - start;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

For high-performance computing in Java you might consider usi JNI (Java Native Interface) - though it requires C++ knowledge. For a quick start take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: At first, Java has been used for years in HPC, for example by IBM. Secondly, his computations are quite simple, C would only give a speedup in a few very specific cases. Thirdly, he never stated that he targets Android and JNI is supported by J2SE in desktop environments. Finally, his problem comes from a naive use of hash maps.