# How can I get a value from a map with a key?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to find a specific object. I'm using the following code, but it seem like `get` only sends back a Boolean that verifies that there is a key with this name, but not an array of Boolean values that I need to use in my program:

```
private Map<User, ArrayList<Boolean>> userDayOfVacationMap;

public ArrayList<Boolean> getUserVacationList(User key){
  return this.userDayOfVacationMap.get(key);
}
```

Is there a method for this?

Here is the `User` object:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Vacation> vacations;
  public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
  }

  public User(){}

  public Set<Vacation> getVacations() {
    return vacations;
  }
  public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }
  public Integer getId(){
    return this.id;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }   
}
```

However, I can't add a variable in this function, because it would add non-useful information into my database.

Comment: What is `String key` vs `User` in map key? What is `DayOfVacation`?

Comment: Can you please show your population code?  What's populating the `userDayOfVacationMap`?

Comment: Your map has `User` objects as keys but the method is given a `String` key. Which one is correct?

Comment: i just corect it, User is the correct one.

Comment: what is a population code?

Comment: Now you're returning `ArrayList<DayOfVacation>` from the map per the method signature but the map is declared to store `ArrayList<Boolean>`. Which one is correct?

Comment: the correct one is boolean, i make the change

Comment: After your edit the method looks fine. If you don't get anything, did you implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` in  `User` and make sure there is an entry in the map?

Comment: Thanks. Now you should let us know what your exact problem is and whether the `User` class has `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods implemented (please share more code).

Comment: i hade the object user, i don't know what are those methode `equals()` and `hascode()`

Comment: Please clarify what your actual problem is. [Why are custom objects not equivalent keys for a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241927/why-are-custom-objects-not-equivalent-keys-for-a-hashmap) has more information about why you should implement those methods in `User` or use `String` keys instead.

Comment: that work now with the correction on the method, thanks